# height 100% de la pantalla dentro de un fixed

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, height

Estaba intentando hacer una navbar desplegable pero al desplegarse no ocupa el 100% de la pantalla ya que la lista de dentro coge el 100% de la navbar no de la pantalla:

```
<nav>
  <a href="../index.html">
    <span class="main-text"><img src="../imgs/white-black-PNG.png" style="width: 55px">TITULO</span>
  </a>
  </button>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="inicio.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="games.html"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>Games</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="edits.html"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Edits</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="random.html"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>Random</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="hamburger" onclick="someFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

la navbar tiene las siguientes propiedades:

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

Cuando la lista se despliega lo pongo 100% pero solo coge el 100% de la nav, es decir que sólo se alarga 80px. He probado en ponerle mucha height para que en cualquier pantalla se vea completo pero no puedo poner los elementos de forma proporcional, la uncia solución es adaptar la lista

--- EDIT ---

Las propiedades de la lista son las siguientes:

```
ul#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: al agregar un 100% es el 100% del contenedor en el que está... Nav en este caso, debe estar dentro de otra cosa.

Comment: No queda claro tu problema y tampoco es reproducible porque no adjuntas el código suficiente para hacerlo. Si fijas el `height: 80px;` es totalmente normal que el css respete ese height en los hijos si utilizas una medida relativa porcentual. ¿Cómo haces el despliegue del menú? ¿Qué clase le agregas? ¿Con qué código? Checa las unidades vw y vh relativas al ancho de las pantallas y por favor, aclara tu problema editando tu pregunta.

Comment: No toma el 100% porq es un elemento que salio del flujo (fixed, absolut, etc) esta flotando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que encontré son varios: no estas definiendo bien tu CSS para obtener el efecto desplegable que quieres; no estas definiendo el estilo para el efecto pantalla completa; y la forma que llamas al evento con el `onclick=""` no es necesario así.

Si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer, realice un cambio para lograr el efecto desplegable correcto del menú:

```css
nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 15;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}

/* Desplega nav */
nav.abrir {
 height: 100%;
 /* Efecto suave */
 background: rgba(0,128,0, 0.5)
}

/* Si ul está dentro de nav, no es necesario ponerlo fijo */
ul#menu {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0,128,0, 0.5)
}

/* Este es a modo de visualización nada más para hacer click */
#hamburger {
 display: block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #000;
 color: #fff
   }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="../index.html">
<span class="main-text"><img src="../imgs/white-black-PNG.png" style="width: 55px">TITULO</span>
  </a>
  </button>
  <div class="main-nav">
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="inicio.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="games.html"><i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>Games</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="edits.html"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>Edits</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="random.html"><i class="fas fa-random"></i>Random</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i>About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="hamburger" onclick="someFunction()">
  Menú
</div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script> // desplegamos menú
let click = document.querySelector("nav")
function someFunction() {
   
 click.classList.toggle("abrir")
}
</script>
```